# For double column format paper, should we use .5\textwidth or a slightly smaller textwidth for a table?

Tags: tables, formatting, adjustbox, textwidth

This is a double-column format paper, and I am using `\adjustbox` to resize my table.

The question is that if I resize my table to `.5\textwidth`, the table is a little bit beyond the text, so should I use `.5\textwidth` or a slightly smaller text width to make the table exact align with the text?

[image]

Comment: This is a tiny point, but I still want to know the standard.

Comment: Why not `\columnwidth`?

Comment: I tried it, but then the table width is way bigger than the text.

Comment: Without the code you are using to produce that table it is hard to know.  Can you please show a compilable example?  `\columnwidth` or `\linewidth` should work.  `\textwidth` takes into account the gap between columns, so you need something like `(\textwidth-\gap)/2`, but that should be `\columnwidth`.

Comment: \columnwidth is the width of the column, but never scale tables with adjustbox or scalebox etc.

Comment: Since you wrote " and I am using \adjustbox to resize my table":  Apart from worrying about the correct width to which you resize your table, you might want to consider not resizing it at all as using `resizebox`, `adjustbox` and the like will result in inconsistent font sizes throughout your document. Depending on the actual table contents, there are better methods to ensure a table fits into the available space.

Comment: @leandrills, thanks, that's a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule you want to use `\linewidth` for the width of the current text line.

`\textwidth` is the width of the whole text block including gutters for multi-column layout.

`\columnwidth` is the width of the current column (which will be `\textwidth` in single column mode).

`\linewidth` adjusts if the margins are changed (e.g., in a list environment or `quotation` environment).

Note that inside a `minipage` environment, `\textwidth` and `\columnwidth` will be reset to the width of the `minipage`.